Robot framework or Python compare dates
I have example date (which must be RFC3339 format)
2021-07-23T14:07:21Z
Next there is an endpoint which takes that date lets say
/setdate
Next I want verify whather it was set OK using another endpoint /getdate for examples.
The problem is that this second endpoit returns this date as
2021-07-23T16:07:21+02:00 whis effectively is the same date but its diffent string so I cant simply compare those two in robot framework.
Are there any robot framework keywords to create two date objects which will be the same when we compare their values?
edit:
How is it possible?
Documentation:  

Fails if the given objects are unequal.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20240513 21:06:22.031 / 20240513 21:06:22.031 / 00:00:00.000
21:06:22.031    DEBUG   Argument types are:
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>     
21:06:22.031    FAIL    2021-07-23 14:07:21+02:00 != 2021-07-23 12:07:21

how can I compare two datetime objects as they are not as strings???
another big question xDDD
def main():
    d1 ='2021-07-23T14:07:21+00:00'
    d2='2021-07-23T14:07:21Z'
    res = compare_rfc_dates(d1, d2)
    print(res)

prints:
2021-07-23 14:07:21+00:00 2021-07-23 14:07:21
False

when compared as datetime objects. Somebody can explain what this means?

You don't need any keywords. The formats are the same. The same instant in time is represented in different timezones (offsets to be precise).  If you parse both dates into a Python datetime with datetime.fromisoformat  you'll get values that are considered equal

datetime.fromisoformat('2021-07-23T14:07:21Z')==datetime.fromisoformat('2021-07-23T16:07:21+02:00') returns True

Im sorry butValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-07-23T14:07:21Z'

It's not. The code works as-is. What did you actually try? What Python version are you using?

Just to peace everybody in the comment section; in RF and using python standard libraries:
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
${DATE1}        2021-07-23T14:07:21Z
${DATE2}        2021-07-23T16:07:21+02:00


*** Keywords ***
Convert Date From Iso Format
  [Documentation]      fromisoformat() requires python 3.11 for certain formats!
  [Arguments]    ${dt}
  ${ret}=   Evaluate   datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("${dt}")   modules=datetime
  RETURN   ${ret}


*** Test Cases ***
Compare the dates take 1
    [Documentation]    Compares DATE1 and DATE2 variables by converting them to datetime objects
    ...                and using builtin Should Be Equal keyword
    ${newdate1}        Convert Date From Iso Format    ${DATE1}
    ${newdate2}        Convert Date From Iso Format    ${DATE2}
    Should Be Equal    ${newdate1}    ${newdate2}

Compare the dates take 2
  [Documentation]    Compares DATE1 and DATE2 variables by converting them to datetime objects and using Evaluate keyword
  ...                to compare them and returns boolean value to be used in Should Be True keyword
  ${ret}=   Evaluate   datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("${DATE1}")==datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("${DATE2}")   modules=datetime
  Should Be True    ${ret}


How is it possible that it works for you but doesn't work for me? :)
Compare the dates take 1 :: Compares DATE1 and DATE2 variables by ... | FAIL |
Evaluating expression 'datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-07-23T14:07:21Z")' failed: ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-07-23T14:07:21Z'
Compare the dates take 2 :: Compares DATE1 and DATE2 variables by ... | FAIL |
Evaluating expression
'datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-07-23T14:07:21Z")==datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-07-23T16:07:21+02:00")' failed: ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-07-23T14:07:21Z'

Because im running on 3.11 -  This works ONLY  from 3.11 and upwards https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#datetime

How did I forget Evaluate? :D This is the right answer, upvoted!

@rasjani
I've fixed this with some kind of workaround :)
def parse_rfc3339_date(d):
if d.endswith("Z") or d.endswith('z'):
d=re.sub('[Zz]$', '+00:00',d)
return datetime.fromisoformat(d)
else:
return datetime.fromisoformat(d)
Cheers

Robot Framework has the DateTime Library for handling date and time values. Not sure if it can be used in your case. If not, then you can create your own keyword in Python to convert the date to UTC and compare the dates in RF using the BuiltIn Should Be Equal keyword.
Example date_convert.py:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

def convert_date_to_utc(datetime_stamp):
    dt = datetime.fromisoformat(datetime_stamp)
    dt_utc = dt - dt.utcoffset()
    formatted_utc = dt_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return formatted_utc

Example date_compare.robot:
*** Settings ***
Library        DateTime
Library        test.py

*** Variables ***
${DATE1}        2021-07-23T14:07:21Z
${DATE2}        2021-07-23T16:07:21+02:00

*** Test Cases ***
Compare the dates
    ${newdate1}        Convert Date    ${DATE1}    result_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    ${newdate2}        test.Convert Date To Utc    datetime_stamp=${DATE2}
    Should Be Equal    first=${newdate1}    second=${newdate2}

This resulted in PASS. Hope this helps.

datetime is a built-in Python library, not a Robot Framework library. UTC isn't a format either, it's the time at the 00:00 timezone offset. convert_date_to_utc doesn't do what it claims, and nothing after fromisoformat serves any purpose

@PanagiotisKanavos  DateTime is also built-in library in Robot Framework.  It does utilize datetime and time under the hood as its mainly a DSL on top of python.

That from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone imports the Python libraries. datetime.fromisoformat is the built-in Python method and returns a timezone-aware datetime object. There's no reason to convert to a local time, much less string, to compare timezone-aware datetime values. datetime.fromisoformat('2021-07-23T14:07:21Z')==datetime.fromisoformat('2021-07-23T16:07:21+02:00') returns True

Yes and ? Your comment still factually incorrect when saying DateTime is not built-in robot framework keyword library.  Do understand this; your code is 100% correct in pure python but in context of RF - there might be intricacies that might not be clear  to you ?

@PanagiotisKanavos
Python 3.9.18 and for me this expression returns error. Do you know why? :)
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-07-23T14:07:21Z'

That's an old version of Python. The current one is 3.12
